# Weighted sum of two normal distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X,Y,Z$ be three standard normal distribution : $X,Y,Z \overset{d}{=} N(0,1)$ but $X,Y,Z$ are not necessarily jointly distributed.

Let $w_X, w_Y,w_Z \in \mathbb{R}$.

We know that if $w_X =w_Y$, we can easily construct $Y=-X$ such as the sum $S=w_X X +w_Y Y=X+Y =0$.

If $w_X \neq w_Y$, can we construct $X$ and $Y$ such as the sum $S=w_X X +w_Y Y = 0$ (or equal to a constant)  as well?

What about the sum $S=w_X X +w_Y Y + w_Z Z$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial answer: $X=tY$ with $t \neq \pm 1$ is impossible. This is because $X=t^{n}Y$ and $|X|=|t|^{n}|Y|$ which tends to $\infty$ if $|t|>1$ and to $0$ is $|t|<1$.

The last one is possible in some cases and not possible in others. For example, we can find $X,Y,Z$ if $w_x=\frac 1 {\sqrt 2}=w_y$ and $w_z=-1$. Take $X,Y$ i.i.d  $N(0,1)$ and $Z=\frac {X+Y} {\sqrt 2}$. In general this is not possible and this is is clear from what we proved above. [Take $w_z=0$ and $w_y=2w_x$ for example].

Comment: I'm sorry but what you wrote is not correct.

Comment: I meant to say $w_x=-w_y=1$. @NN2

Comment: In the first sentence, $w_x,w_y,w_z$ are given, so you don't have $w_z=0$.
In the second sentence, I don't know why you use limit here. And if $t \neq \pm 1$, how both of  $X$ and $Y$ can follow a standard normal distribution $N(0,1)$ ?

Comment: If $w_xX+w_yY=0$ with $X,Y$ both standard normal then we must have $w_x =\pm w_y$. I am proving this statement by taking $t$ to be $-\frac {w_y} {w_x}$. @NN2

Comment: Ok, thank you. I see now. In fact, if $w_x X =-w_y Y$, so $V(w_x X) = V(w_y Y)$, we must have  $w_x^2 = w_y^2$ as the condition so that $S=0$.

Comment: @NN2 I have now answered the last part also.

Comment: Thank you. 
For the second part, I think we can find the necessary and sufficient condition for $S=0$.
At the moment, I think the necessary conditions are: $w_x,w_y,w_z \neq 0$, they are 3 sides of a triangle (eg. $w_x+w_y \geq w_z$) and $1+ 3w_x w_y w_z -(w_x^2+w_y^2+w_z^2) >0$.